# Always getting error during apt-get install

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to do apt-get install/upgrade, I always get a series of errors like below. Is it because of some incorrect entries in /etc/apt/sources.list file. If so, how to correct it?

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
      linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libxerces-c3.1
    Suggested packages:
      gstreamer1.0-ffmpeg
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libxerces-c3.1
    0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 11.7 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 39.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
    WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
      libxerces-c3.1 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
    Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Y
    Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe libxerces-c3.1 amd64 3.1.1-3
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 amd64 1.10.2-0ubuntu1
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libwebkitgtk-1.0-common all 1.10.2-0ubuntu1
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 amd64 1.10.2-0ubuntu1
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xerces-c/libxerces-c3.1_3.1.1-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_1.10.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit/libwebkitgtk-1.0-common_1.10.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_1.10.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail), please note that it has reached the EOL. Better to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or newer.

Answer (score 1):

1. First make sure that you have installed the applications gksu and leafpad

   Launch a terminal window.

Type (or copy/paste):

```
sudo apt-get install gksu leafpad
```

Press Enter and submit your password. Please note that the password will remain invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is normal.

2 . Then remove all sources that you have now:

Launch a terminal window.

Type (use copy/paste to avoid errors):

```
sudo rm -vf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list && sudo rm -vf /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Press Enter. Type your password when prompted; this will remain entirely invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is normal.

3. Create a new sources list:

Copy/paste the following command into the terminal:

```
gksudo leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Press Enter.

Now copy/paste all the text below, into that empty text file:

```
## SOURCES LIST FOR UBUNTU 14.04 LTS TRUSTY TAHR
## ALSO FOR XUBUNTU 14.04, LUBUNTU 14.04
## AND KUBUNTU 14.04
## From: http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject
## This list is for the Main server; you might want to select a
## faster mirror server closer to you, with Software & Updates.
## Only fit for 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr!
#
## SOURCES FOR ORDINARY SOFTWARE:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
#
## SOURCES FOR SECURITY UPDATES:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
#
## BACKPORTS SOURCES (WITH LOWERED PRIORITY):
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports multiverse
#
## PARTNER SOURCE (FOR SOFTWARE FROM
## BUSINESS PARTNERS OF CANONICAL):
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
#
## INDEPENDENT SOURCE (FOR SOFTWARE
## FROM THIRD-PARTY DEVELOPERS):
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
#
## SOURCE FOR WEB BROWSER GOOGLE CHROME
## (DISABLED BY DEFAULT):
## Only enable it when you've installed Google Chrome!
## You can enable it in the application Software & Updates.
# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Save the text file and close it.

4. Now reload the sources list information:

In the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Press Enter and submit your password. Please note that the password will remain invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is normal.

You're done!

Comment: One can use sudo instead of gksudo and any text editor(vim/gedit/sublime) instead of leafpad to paste that code. Just remember that due to use of #, askubuntu has converted a comment to bold line. Just insert # in front of every bold line and don't copy that last line '============='. You are good to go.