# deleted sources.list.d from apt directory

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-uninstall

I ran the following command in order to reinstall my broken apt-get system:-

```
sudo rm -vf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list && sudo rm -vf /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I was following the steps from this answer([Always getting error during apt-get install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652603/always-getting-error-during-apt-get-install)) but gksu package is not installed.

What are the next steps to follow now?

Comment: I have no idea what made you do that; but may I suggest **not** running a update command.  Why did you consider your `apt-get` system broken?  (possibly you were supposed to remove /var/lib/apt/lists/....)

Comment: @guiverc I was getting similar errors (as asked in this https://askubuntu.com/questions/652603/always-getting-error-during-apt-get-install) on every installation. 
But since apt-get was not working properly, gksu and leafpad packages are  not completely installed.
Is there anything I can do now?

Comment: given you were following that answer, I'd continue with those steps. leadpad is only an editor, if it were me I'd type `sudo vim ...` (ie. used the vim editor; by default only vi is installed so if you've not used vim, substitute vi/nano/.. or whatever editor you like in place of leafpad).   Please put info such as following (answer..) in your question..  [why sudo and not gksudo - mostly its what my fingers type :) ]   ps: if you don't know vi/vim - try `nano` in place of leafpad (or gedit [if installed])

Comment: try using `sudo` instead of `gksudo`  (and `gksu`)

Comment: after sudo-apt update, it's giving me following error....  

    `E: Type 'SOURCES' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
    E: The list of sources could not be read.`
PS:- I used sudo and sublime @guiverc

Comment: *correction in above comment: after `sudo apt-get update`....

Comment: Line 1 will contain an error/typo etc.  if you add it here (best in question as addendum etc as more formatting & editing allowed there) I can tell you what's wrong.  Alternatively just add a # at beginning of line 1 and the line will be ignored (# as first character makes line a comment)

Comment: Yes it's working fine now. Thanks for the help. @guiverc

Comment: It's good to include it in your daily backup: `tar -rvpf "$FileName" /etc/apt/sources.list` and `tar -rvpf "$FileName" /etc/apt/sources.list.d` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @guiverc said, follow the answer you are following.
You can use `sudo` instead of `gksudo` and any text editor(vim/gedit/sublime) instead of leafpad to paste that code.
Just remember that due to use of #, askubuntu has converted a comment to bold line.
Just insert `#` in front of every bold line (otherwise that `the list cannot be read` will keep coming) and don't copy that last line `=============`. You are good to go.