# I messed up my packages and can't get them to work. Dependencies missing

Tags: command-line, package-management, dependencies

As the title states, I messed up. I don't know exactly where (I was trying to install *runescape*), but I did. Now, there are about a hundred dependencies missing. So many that I can't get them on one scroll up.

I've tried many things (all the obvious ones of course):

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
```

I've also tried with `dpkg`. I found this, which told me to do this:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}' > list.log
awk '$1=$1' ORS=' ' list.log > newlist.log
apt-get install --reinstall $(cat newlist.log)
```

None of it worked.

No packages are on hold for dpkg. I've checked. Twice.

`sudo apt-get -f install` returns the same errors that any other package install returns because of unmet dependencies.

Here's the error it gives me:

```
<bunch of dependencies listed>
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I also managed to delete `sources.list.d` at some point and I don't even really know what it's good for.

I seriously am out of my depth. I have no clue. Help.

Comment: Please show us a complete terminal session showing the error(s) you are encountering and how you got there. And stop trying random commands you find on the internet - seems like you are making the problem worse.

Comment: I don't know how to show the complete terminal session, as I can't scroll up far enough to reach the start of the dependency errors

Comment: That's a setting in your Terminal application. You may need to restart the Terminal application for the changed setting to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restoring your `sources.list.d` with the help of [Always getting error during apt-get install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652603/always-getting-error-during-apt-get-install)

And for your package installation error, run...

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This should work.

Comment: @CiaranHagen your welcome. And don't forget to mark the solution. :)

Comment: Ok, this is weird. It seemed as if it worked temporarily, but I still can't install anything...
Now instead of a billion errors, when I do ```apt-get -f install```, it just gives me ```error while loading shared libraries: libattr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That's a different problem. Search for it - it's been asked and answered here before.